# Listen for Function Keys in Logitech G Lua Script

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have a Logtech G915 TKL keyboard, and it has programmable function keys. You can write scripts that listen for special keys on Logitech G hardware (such as the G Keys or the M Keys) using the scripting feature in Logitech G Hub.

I would like to write a script that listens for when I press the F1 key and does some action. Here's my attempt:

```lua
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    --Listen for F1 (G10) key press event
    if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 10) then
        --Do some action (e.g. press the "a" key)
        PressAndReleaseKey(30);
        SLeep(50);
    end
end
```

My attempt was based off the assumption that Logitech might consider the F1-12 keys to be additional G keys. My mouse has 9 G keys, so I guessed that F1 might be G10.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can not.  G915's specifications on logitech's website says that the keyboard has only 5 G-keys.  Some other Logitech keyboards (such as my G413) do not have additional left-side-buttons G1,G2,.., instead they treat F1-F12 as G1-G12.  But your keyboard has only 5 G-keys.